# User Defined Program to calculate fields

Tags: java, integration, logical-operators, sap-erp, sap-xi

I have to take a document from SAP ERP and then send it out through a CSV file with values delimited by pipes (`|`).

The configuration works, I built it, mapped some segments... but I don't know how to map a specific segment which I'm asked to map thru User-Defined function (logic via Java).

All I have is this:

**Target Field**: `AdjProductNum` (numeric value)

**IDoc segment**: `ZMSEG`

**Logic to code**: `When BWART = 309 AND MATNR <> UMMAT AND ( WERKS= UMWRK AND LGORT = UMLGO AND CHARG = UMCHA); = UMMAT`

This is the logic I have designed with help of a colleague:

```
public class CheckIdocProductNum {

    public static void  CheckIDocProductNum(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              // code to check AdjProductNum

              if (BWART.equals("309") && 
                      !MATNR.equals(UMMAT) &&
                      WERKS.equals(UMWRK) &&
                      LGORT.equals(UMLGO) &&
                      CHARG(UMCHA)) 
               return UMMAT; // Condition fulfilled

              else = FAIL;// Returns blank if does not fulfill IF    
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is very broad that makes it very hard to help. You are talking about ERP, sending CSV, and how to use a Java IDE.. Show us what you have tried so far and what the recent issue is you encountered. Post a new question for the next issue you tripped over and so on

Comment: That would best fit Super User web site or SAP Community forum because it's a very general question. Your question seems to concern SAP Process Integration (SAP PI/XI/PO). I understand that PI receives an IDoc from a SAP ERP system that you have to convert into a CSV file. The IDoc has a `ZMSEG` segment with fields BWART, MATNR and so on, which are the inputs to calculate a field in the CSV file that you named `AdjProductNum`. For entering the calculation rule, you may either use java or simple operations and conditions. That's all I know.

Comment: `The configuration works, I built it, mapped some segments` Tell us what you built, show your PI mapping

Comment: @SandraRossi correct. Thank you. I've edited the question with what I have done. I tried the SAP forum but I'm not getting answers there.